# The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I'm intending to create pagination on my api using the following example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073488/Paging-in-ASP-NET-Web-API 
I've implemented all code and its running until I hit the following line of code:

```
var results = await projection.ToListAsync();
```

then it causes a runtime error:

> "The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider..."

I've researched this error and tried to initialize the Mapper in my Global.asax.cs file like so:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Logging.Models.LogsModel, Log>());
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    }
```

This doesn't resolve the problem, does anybody know what I'm doing wrong initializing Automapper?

Thanks in Advance.

Here is the implementing code in my controller:

```
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int? page = null, int pageSize = 10, string orderBy = nameof(LogsModel.Id), bool ascending = true)
    {
        if (page == null)
        {
            return Ok(_repository.GetLogs());
        }
        else
        {
            var returnList =  _repository.GetLogs().AsQueryable();
            returnList = returnList as IQueryable<LogsModel>;
            var logsout = await CreatePagedResults<LogsModel, Log>(returnList, page.Value, pageSize, orderBy, ascending);
            return Ok(logsout);
        }
    }
```

and heres the definition of GetLogs:

```
        public IEnumerable<LogsModel> GetLogs()
    {
        List<LogsModel> logs = Logs.ToList<LogsModel>();
        return logs;
    }
```

Comment: What is your data source here? The `global.asax.cs` file is not relevant at all.

Comment: Side note: You could also use the [asp.net webapi implementation of OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/) to achieve paging, filtering, and sorting without having to write any of the implementing code. The client would be responsible for sending the correct query string that contains what it wants to retrieve. The c# code would strictly focus on the business model.

Comment: entity framework 6.1.3 ---> Sql Server

Comment: What is the concrete type of the IQueryable in your situation?

Comment: recheck the question i've added my controller thanks

Comment: I've also stepped through it and the data is being passed

Comment: SQL Server's `IQueryable` does support `IDbAsyncQueryProvider`, so whatever you're returning from `GetLogs()` must be something else. Most likely the problem is in `GetLogs`.

Comment: Is the problem that I'm sending it to the controller as an IEnumerable type then converting it to IQueryable in my controller?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, the problem was that I used System.Data.Entity instead of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

I just replaced:

using System.Data.Entity; with
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Because both namespaces has equal methods for example SingleOrDefaulAsync, but in System.Data.Entity this method has InvalidOperationException source doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider
see more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.singleordefaultasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_QueryableExtensions_SingleOrDefaultAsync__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Boolean___System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Comment: I use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore but still get the error.